# Laravel ajax post(Can't find ajax request)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to send ajax request in laravel 5.1. but i can't get ajax request. it always HTTP request.

I have a html form

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="/admin/save-drug" id="add_drug">

<label for="drugs_name">Drug Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="drugs_name" id="drugs_name">

<label for="drugs_name">Drug Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="drugs_name" id="drugs_name">

<button type="submit" id="save_drug" class="btn btn-default waves-effect waves-light btn-md">
</form>
```

And i use ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#add_drug').submit(function  (){
                $.ajax({
                    url: './admin/save-drug',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data : { 'drugs_name':$('input[name=drugs_name]').val()},

                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data)
                        }
                });
            });
        });
```

My Controller

```
public function saveDrug(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()){
            return "AJAX";
        }else{
            return "HTTP";
        }
    }
```

It alwayes return "HTTP"
what's wrong with my code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in your code, there isn't anything stopping the form from submitting as the browser normally would.

My guess is that if you open your inspector, turn on saving the network log, and submit the form, you will see both your AJAX request and the standard form submission.

I think you may need to arrest the form submission event so that it does not bubble, allowing your AJAX to run, but stopping the form from submitting as normal.

Here's what the JavaScript would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_drug').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //Stop the form from submitting
        $.ajax({
            url: './admin/save-drug',
            type: 'POST',
            data : { 'drugs_name':$('input[name=drugs_name]').val()},

                success: function(data){
                    alert(data)
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Now it's a new problem, 500 internal server error .
it's maybe cos of csrf token i use 
 headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
into the $.ajax().. but steel it's error

Comment: Check your error logs and see if you can find the actual error - either the Apache log, the nginx log, or laravel's own log if it's in use. Could be anything - syntax error, logic error, reference error, etc. Either way, the core problem of not being able to send an AJAX call without submitting the form appears to be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add csrf_token

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function(){
            var token='{{csrf_token()}}';
                $('#add_drug').submit(function  (){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: './admin/save-drug',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data : { 'drugs_name':$('input[name=drugs_name]').val(),_token:token},
                            success: function(data){
                                alert(data)
                            }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: I use csrf_token() already in my master blade

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });
</script>

Comment: please check if you have error on your console. No problem on me.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined
is js console error. do u have any solution ??